# Multiple records from DB and process with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I need idea..

I am using Jquery, PHP, Mysql
I want to bring 10 records from DB. It is like a quiz. So once the first question is answered, then i want to bring the second question. So it will reduce the Mysql overload.

After the 10th question, I want to again bring 10 questions from DB.

** I am planning to do with Ajax.
** While bring the questions and answers, users should not see the results in console if they know how to use firbug or other tools.

How do i acheive this? Or Is there any other good way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your questions. Are they multiple choice, short answer, etc? It matters because it determines what event you are going to listen for. For example in multiple choice, I would use the onchange event for the radio button group. If you have your users hit a button to move to the next question, then you can easily tie a listener to that kind of event `$('#button').click(function(){//perform ajax here});

For your ajax call, you need to determine how to know what the next question is, then simply write a php page that gets the next question after you supply an answer to the current one. For example, if the questions are in order of id, you could pass the id and the person's answer in the ajax call, save the answer, and get the next question:

Javascript:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myurl.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {answer: $('#answer').val(), 'question_id': question},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('div.questions').append(data);
            question++;
        }
});
});
```

PHP

```
$answer = $_REQUEST['answer'];
$curr_question = $_REQUEST['question'];

//save answer here;

//get next question based off current question

echo <<html for next question >>

etc...
```